# Small Caps in Gentium Plus after MiKTeX update

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex, small-caps

I'm using Gentium Plus under `XeTeX` for quite a long time now, and it always worked like a charm. However, after updating `MiKTeX` (I'm running version 2.9.4902 now), small caps are not displayed properly anymore, though the font surely includes small caps (that's what they say on the SIL webpage).

I get a warning:

```
Font shape 'EU1/GentiumPlus(0)/m/sc' undefined(Font) using 'EU1/GentiumPlus(0)/m/n' instead
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}
\textsc{testtext}
\end{document}
```

What should I do? I need to use a font that has full Unicode support and small caps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the Renderer: `\setmainfont[Renderer=ICU,Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium Plus}`